# $f\in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ then there is a subseq $(f_{n_k})$ that converges to $f$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:\Omega\to[-\infty,\infty]$. We suppose that there is a sequence $f_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, converging to $f$ in $L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Show that there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ converging to $f$ $\mu-$a.e., that is $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_{n_k}(\omega) = f(\omega)$ for $\mu-$a.e. $\omega\in\Omega$.

Attempted proof:

If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$ then, there also a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ of $f_n$ converging to $f$ in $L^1$, ie. 
$\int|f_n-f|d\mu=\int|f_{n_k}-f|d\mu=0.$ Now assume $f_{n_k}$ also converges to $f$ a.e. then (using the definition of a.e. convergence) $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\sup_{n_k\geq n}|f_{n_k}-f|>\epsilon)\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int|f_{n_k}-f|d\mu=\int|f_n-f|d\mu=0.$ Where I used Markov inequality.

Probably still a lot of mistakes in this attempt, but I am happy with any feedback.

Comment: You will need to construct the subsequence, i.e., direct the selection of its elements, with the a.e. convergence in mind, You can not assume that any random subsequence has this property.

Comment: This is no proof at all - at one point you _assume_ exactly what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Yes, but this inequality is only true, if such a subsequence exists.

Comment: So what? You're asked to show that some subsequence converges to $f$ almost everywhere; you can't do that by assuming that a subsequence convreges to $f$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Choose a subsequence with $$\sum_k||f-f_{n_k}||_1<\infty.$$Apply Monotone Convergence to conclude that $$\int\sum|f_{n_k}-f|<\infty.$$Hence $\sum|f_{n_k}-f|<\infty$ almost everywhere...

Comment: But I don't have to choose $f_{n_k}$ explicitly, right? I can just say that $|f-f_{n_k}|$ is smaller than $\frac{1}{2^k}$ . But why, why does this imply that there exists such a subsequence?

Comment: If $a_n\to0$ there exists a siubsequence with $a_{n_k}<2^{-k}$.; this is clear from the definition.